# Error Failed to install the app. I have a problem with my project, i use a socket io, react native, and react native sms x

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, socket.io, sms

I don't know what I can do with this error. I've tried everything I know, and nothing seems to work. In this app, I use a socketio, gradle, android, react native sms x.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SmsApp> npm run android

> SmsApp@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info JS server already running.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tasks'.
> Could not create task ':react-native-socketio:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   > In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
error Failed to install the app.
```

I've attempted numerous options, but none of them have worked.